# Do we say "she twisted / sprained her foot" in everyday English?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> [sprain](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sprain) /spreɪn/ ●○○ verb [transitive]
>
> to damage a joint in your body by suddenly twisting it SYN twist
>
> I fell down the steps and sprained my ankle.

---

> [twist your ankle/wrist/knee](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/twist-your-ankle-wrist-knee) to hurt your wrist etc by pulling or
>   turning it too suddenly while you are moving
>
> Harriet slipped on the stairs and twisted her ankle.

Look at the picture

[image]

Sometimes, we accidentally **stand on the side of our foot** & may hurt it.

Do we say "**she twisted / sprained her foot**" in everyday English?

Comment: Yes, and you could have easily confirmed this with a web search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"She twisted her ankle" or "She sprained her ankle" are both correct, but I wouldn't regard it as wrong if someone said "foot" instead of ankle in either case.  It might imply a slightly different location for the injury.

So far as twisted vs. sprained, if it caused temporary pain and she can "walk it off", I'd say twisted.  If it caused enough damage that she had to wrap her foot or use crutches, I'd say sprained.  Sprained has slight connotations of a more serious injury than twisted.  But this is a subtle difference and not a matter of correctness.

Answer (score 0):

For that set of pictures, I would say "I twisted my foot, and thus sprained my ankle."